# Postman responseBody JSON getting all the users

Tags: json, postman

i am trying to create a runner in postman, but first i need to get all the usernames from some JSON, however i am having problems getting a list of all the usernames from the following JSON.

```
      var data = JSON.parse(responseBody); 
      $.each(data.users, function (key, data) {

            console.log(key);

      });


      {
        "ok": true,
        "users": {
          "U02FJJD3M": {
            "dnd_enabled": false
          },
          "U02FPPT59": {
            "dnd_enabled": false
          },
          "U02FQENJU": {
            "dnd_enabled": true
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work.

```
var result = { "ok": true, "users": { "john": { "dnd_enabled": false, }, "sam": { "dnd_enabled": false, }, "sarah": { "dnd_enabled": true, } } };

var names = Object.keys(result.users);
```